# Правильно ли расставлены запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Мы жертвуем, кто сколько может, из своего семейного бюджета.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно.

Кто сколько может - это упрощенный оборот на основе придаточного, его обособление зависит от положения в предложении.

В данном положении оборот удобно обособить, как распространенный второстепенный член в  добавочном сообщении. Этот же оборот можно не обособлять в следующем предложении: Мы жертвуем кто сколько может.

Comment: Видимо, возможен и такой вариант (со своим оттенком):
"Мы жертвуем кто сколько может - из своего семейного бюджета."
Здесь основное суждение состоит в том, что "мы жертвуем вовсю", а затем идёт пояснение "откуда денежки берутся". При этом тире "освежает" действие глагола, ранее связанного только с "размером жертв", замещая пропущенное повторение "мы жертвуем". Развёрнутый вариант этой же фразы был бы таким:
"Мы жертвуем кто сколько может[, а жертвуем мы] из своего семейного бюджета."